# How do I apply Google Analytics on AngularJS partials and page titles?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, google-analytics

I am trying to track all of the pages on my website using Google Analytics. My website has several partials using $routeProvider and the ng-view directive in the index.html file. When I put the Google Analytics code snippet in the index.html file, I am only able to track the default route "/". How do I make it so Google Analytics can track all of the activity within  each partial page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this simple module
https://github.com/doodeec/dc-angular-analytics

it creates an analytics service and tracks every page view

Comment: Nice. A few things though: 1. include the License information in the .js file (copyright, author, link to MIT license etc) and the Git repo. 2. UNIT TESTS! Even if it's simple, some organizations won't touch untested code. 3. Minified version?  Try grunt-contrib-uglify or Google Closure compiler.